# Determine the value of the real number A so that a finite limit exists, and then compute the limit:

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

Determine the value of the real number A so that a finite limit exists, and then compute the limit:  $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} (\sqrt{Ax^2 + 2x} - 5x)$$

I really have no clue how to even get started.

Comment: $A=25$ is the value of $A$ so that your limit is finite.